# Reset JqGrid search string

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I need to reset the search string after a search is performed.

I tried changing the search column but the search string is not resetting.

How can I reset the search string from search popup?

Answer (score 0):

I am mot sure that I understand correctly what you want. Probably you problem will be solved by the usage of `recreateFilter: true` searching [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options). Probably you need clear `filters` (in case of usage of `multipleSearch: true`) or `searchString` property (in case of usage single field searching) of `postData` in the `onClose`:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    recreateFilter: true,
    onClose: function () {
        delete $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters;
    }
});
```

It can be that you need don't load any default filter at all in the searching dialog:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.search, {
    multipleSearch: true,
    recreateFilter: true,
    loadDefaults: false
});
```

All depends from your requirements. You should try different options which I described above and if the Searching Dialog do not what you need you should describe your requirements more clear.

Answer (score 0):

For reset all filters in searchpopup in jqgrid use `recreateFilter: true`.

For closing searchpopup in jqgrid after search completion use `closeAfterSearch:true`.

**jqgrid**

```
$("#loggerList").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerDiv',{},{},{},{},
{closeAfterSearch:true, recreateFilter: true});
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="padding:10px;">
    <div id="gridContainer">
        <table id="loggerList"></table>
        <div id="pagerDiv"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```